# How to make a countdown timer in C?

Tags: c, countdown

I am trying to make a countdown timer in C wherein it will have two goals:

- Take the current date and time depending on timezone the program will
  be run in
- User input the date and time to acquire a countdown against
  current date and time

I'm struggling to figure out how to get the current time properly as some codes I found online despite being cryptic is showing a wrong output (Date will be shown correctly however time is wrong) and I' dont know how to compare this against user input as I dont know how to use for loops in a complex way.

My expected output as an example:

{

Current date and time : Aug 6, 2022 10:00:01PM

Enter date for countdown: (User prompt)

-- ***prints a countdown every second until the date is met in format (mm/dd/yy hh:mm:ss)*** --

}

TLDR;

- Is this possible in C language?
- What tools can I use for this program?

Comment: It's definitely possible to do this only in C. However, you need to find a good library for parsing dates. I did a quick google search and it seems there are some libraries out there. Anyway, the countdown itself will be pretty easy, because dates are usually stored and dealt with the unix timestamp format. It's an unsigned integer that starts from a fixed date: `This count starts at the Unix Epoch on January 1st, 1970 at UTC.`. So counting down to the date itself is a matter of waiting until the current timestamp matches (or exceeds) the future timestamp.

Comment: Regarding your second query, requesting tools/libs and/or other offsite resource recommendations is off-topic on this site. So don't expect much.

Comment: Please post the example code which reports the incorrect time. FYI Microsoft lists various C time management functions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/time-management?view=msvc-170).

Comment: The `strptime` function can take a date string and produce a "broken down" time struct: `struct tm`. With that, it can be passed to `mktime/gmtime` to get a `time_t` which is an "absolute number of seconds since the epoch". You can repeat this for both the current time and future time so you end up with two binary numbers that you can compare. You can get current time with: `time_t curtime = time(NULL);` so you really only need to parse the string input by the user. You could parse the string manually and create the `struct tm` from it. Then, do `mktime`